# Can't serialize byte array in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, binding, arrays

I'm using a WCF API and a can't serialize an object with a byte array when I try to make Download of a file. The file size is small: 104 bytes. 
The object is:

```
[DataContract]
  public class File
 {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public byte[] Data { get; set; }

}
```

I've tried to use KnownType(typeof(byte)), KnownType(typeof(byte[])) and KnownType(typeof(Array)) in the class, but without sucess.

I've also tried to return a string with Base64 of the byte array, but it didn't work.

I have no error message in the client side. The WCF just doesn't return the object until I receive the TimeOut message (I've waiting more than 1 minute).
I also tried to change the sizes in the web config. There are my bindings configurations:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
             closeTimeout="0:10:00" openTimeout="1:10:00" receiveTimeout="1:10:00" sendTimeout="1:10:00" allowCookies="false" 
             messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <reliableSession enabled="true" inactivityTimeout="00:25:00"/>
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Plase, help me!!

Comment: You've changed it for the server, but is your client binding configured to receive  message sizes larger than the default 16K?

Comment: I am really confused. Are you using a WCF API or are you making one? why are you trying to serialize or deserialize your download?

Comment: I just reread the question and see that your file is only 104 bytes, not 104K so disregard my other comment.

Comment: @A.sharif I'm using a WCF API, and I doing a method to allow download of files. Not large files. Files with max 20 MegaBytes. I've read a lot of questions here about it, and I've tried all the solutions, like I wrote here. Any of them works for me.

Comment: So you are either a client of a service or you are a service. Which one are you?

Comment: @A.sharif I'm creating the service and a cliente. The problem is in the service. When I try  to return the object File with the atributte Data, the service didn't return nothing, and I get the Timeout error.

Comment: So you need a few things.  You need a [ServiceContract] and a [OperationContract] binding on this class/method. Then you need to create a service endpoint in your webconfig so it can referenced by your client.

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of days I discovered the solution to my problem.
The problem was in the client side, not in the server side, like I thought.
I've forgotten to use the `maxReceivedMessageSize` tag in the client side.
So, I copy everything inside the binding block and I and paste in the client webconfig, and it works.